# Access the USIM Phone Book file using CSIM\CRSM commands

Tags: quectel, usim

I have BG95 modem and IOT SIM.
Im trying to access (read\write) the Phone book entry on the SIM to insert some of our infromation.
On EC25 +CPBW\CPBR are available but not on BG95.
From 3GPP 31.102 i can see that:

- Phone book file MF is 5F3A.
- it's PIN1\2 protected
- each entry is ADNx EF '4F3A'.

I want to access it using CRSM (i have to since it's PIN protected even if there is no SIM PIN). But i could not find any CRSM support for "select file" (A4) like CSIM has.
So either how do i select MF using CRSM if even possible OR
How do i just access the phone book on the SIM using AT commands if other way is applicable, again CPBW\R are not available.